# how can I set the timezone in Linux if there's no /etc/timezone file nor a /usr/share/zoneinfo

Tags: linux, time, timezone, embedded, busybox

I need to set the timezone on a Linux system (embedded busybox distro) but i don't have a /etc/timezone nor a /usr/share/zoneinfo. How do I set the timezone?

I set the hardware clock to utc with:
hwclock --set --date=18:15:30 --utc
and then thought I could use 'export TZ=PST8PDT' in /etc/profile to get the correct time with date but this doesn't seem to work. I still see this:

```
# date
Wed May 30 18:17:42 PDT 2012
```

Thanks!
Ron

Comment: What do you mean by "set the timezone"? What are you going to use as the source of data for (eg) daylight savings changes?

Comment: What libc are you using? If you use [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) it could be `/etc/TZ` ([see](http://www.uclibc.org/FAQ.html#timezones))

Comment: Yes Florian, I am using uclibc and /etc/TZ seems to be the right answer...! :)

Comment: but # cat /etc/TZ 
PST8PDT still doesn't do the trick :(

Comment: @cerr if you want to write to the file you have to call `echo 'PST8PDT' > /etc/TZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had to set the correct timezone in /etc/TZ, set the hwclock to utc with the --set and --utc flags and use hwclock --systohc to store the system time in the hardware clock.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to /etc/inittab:

> setenv TZ CDT

Where CDT (Central) is the timezone.

Comment: I don't have setenv available... :(